# "Starting Wireless Hotspot..." but nothing happens

Tags: wireless, android, hot-spot

I was trying to create an WiFi hotspot for my android device. I used ap-hotspot to do so.

I configured the ap-hotspot using

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

Then I started ap-hotspot using

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

Then it shows this

```
Starting Wireless Hotspot...
```

And then nothing happens, no further message is displayed, hotspot is not created.

What is Wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: After following above steps, ap-hotspot was not working

Comment: use the instructions below as given in the answer,. then configure the ap-hotsot and start,. it should work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ap-hotspot` uses `hostapd` to create wireless network

I had problems creating hotspot using `hostapd` in Ubuntu 14.04 mainly because new version of `hostapd` in 14.04 default repository is buggy.

You can solve this problem by downgrading `hostapd` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to a previous version

Uninstall buggy `hostapd` using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get remove hostapd
```

Then install non-buggy version of hostapd:

- 64 - bit:

  ```
  cd /tmp
  wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
  sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
  ```
- 32 - bit:

  ```
  cd /tmp
  wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
  sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
  sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
  ```

"sudo apt-mark hold hostapd" will prevent hostapd to upgrade to the buggy version.

Then try running `ap-hotspot` again, I think it should work. It worked for me like a charm.

Comment: what is this, it fills up the terminal. bash: notify-send: command not found

Comment: install `notify-send` using `sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin`

Comment: if you use the "sudo apt-get upgrade" will the hostapd upgraded?

Comment: not if you have done `sudo apt-mark hold hostapd`

Comment: Is there no other solution? And is the problem reported and a Bugreport filed?

Comment: This solution not working for me. I have done everything as above. Still getting same problem.

Comment: If you can't get ap-hotspot to work, try kde-nm-connection-editor. It actually works. Here's a tutorial: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/

Comment: The question, this answer, the `sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin` comment by @Back.Slash is just what I need.
_N.B on my side, lubuntu_14.04, `sudo apt-get remove hostapd:i386` was the command for removing `hostapd`._

Answer (score 1):

Install the `hostapd` as mentioned above, followed by `ap-hotspot`, from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/trusty/main/base/ap-hotspot and run

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

Give the correct inter-phase eth0 and wlan0 followed by ssid and pass-phrase.

Start the hotspot by

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

Answer (score 0):

The file:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb

Is no longer present on the ununtu.com server. How do I upgrade the hostapd?

Answer (score 0):

this is old post but i stuck in same problem and i solved my problem .

this problem may be occurs with wrong version but in my case if you are using any other network manager tools and service of that manager is running then it may not work  `ap-hotspot` service and it show

```
 Starting Wireless Hotspot...
```

solution: stop service of previous network manager tools  if you are using default network manager then do

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

or if you using `wicd` then stop it using

```
sudo service wicd stop
```

then you have to start `ap-hotspot`

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```