# ap-hotspot hangs at "starting wireless hotspot" on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hot-spot

I am not an advanced user of ubuntu and I am using Ubuntu 14.04 alongside with Windows 8. When I started ap-hotspot in terminal it hangs at "starting wireless hotspot...." . But I had no problems previously on Ubuntu 13.10. Please suggest any work around.

Comment: post the output of `rfkill list`

Comment: 0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: restart your pc and then try again.

Comment: No improvement, the same output...

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Starting Wireless Hotspot..." but nothing happens](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453877/starting-wireless-hotspot-but-nothing-happens)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use this [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html).

My guess is: you need to downgrade hostapd. It's told how to do it in that tutorial. However, I'll post the code here just in case.

Fot 64-bit:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

For 32-bit:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb` as the package has been removed/moved from the archive.ubuntu.com. So it'll give Not Found error. This link should work.