# Dependency issue installing hostapd

Tags: 14.04, hot-spot

All the time I gets this dependency issue when trying installing hostapd as mentioned here

Ubuntu version 14.04
Arch 64

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you start, purge hostapd and install your dependencies with these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge hostapd
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200
```

I didn't understand what you were trying to do. Here's the answer:

first, back up your sources list with the following command:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources
```

then, change your repositories to saucy from trusty:

```
sudo sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

next, update your package list and install hostapd=1:1.0-3ubuntu2.1 with these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hostapd=1:1.0-3ubuntu2.1
```

now, prevent future updates from changing the hostapd version with this command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

and change your sources list back to the trusty repos and update your package list to trusty:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

finally, install the webupd8 ppa and install ap-hotspot

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

[more info from webupd8 can be found here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html)

---

start ap-hotspot:

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

to reconfigure ap-hotspot anytime after installation, run this command:

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

stop:

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

to see a list of commands:

```
ap-hotspot
```

Last but not least, the default SSID is "myhotspot" and the default password is "qwerty0987".

Comment: thanks I still can not create hotspot explained on here http://askubuntu.com/questions/453877/starting-wireless-hotspot-but-nothing-happens

Comment: @GayanChathuranga Okay, sorry. I completely changed the answer to install the saucy version of hostapd and the webupd8 ap-hotspot. Included are some links and full instructions to get you started. Some cards don't support AP mode so pay attention to the logfiles and errors and if you see AP mode is not supported or similar, you may have to use another wireless adapter that supports AP mode. If all else fails, plasma-nm looks promising as well http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/

Comment: Thx this was exactly looking for to the point