# Does ubuntu wifi sharing process support samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1?

Tags: wireless, networking, android, hot-spot

:)

Lately, I have been trying to share my internet to my android tab(Samsung Galaxy tab 2, 10.1)  via Wifi hotspot.

What I did:

I have used KDE network manager to create a wifi(shared) profile with WPA/WPA2 encryption security. Then, I have connected to that network using "Connect to hidden wifi networks", and it showed that it has been connected.

What is happening:

But, when I am looking for that hotspot using my android tab, the device is not finding the wifi network.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thank you. :)

Information used:
(http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/)
PS:
I am a fresh Ubuntu(linux) OS user :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.

I used this post and it worked finally!

http://codewriteup.blogspot.com/2014/08/tested-working-set-up-wifi-hotspot-on.html

One note: Delete the prior installation of ap-hotspot if applicable!

Comment: @ MuffinStateWide, finally I found a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) method for a while to share between 3 android devices (Nexus 7 , Nexus 9 and Desire 816) as well as the odd laptop and it works without a hitch on Ubuntu 14.10 using unity.

I think the main difference and the only change you may need to make is changing the connection type to `ap` as described in the guide i linked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have followed this tutorial. :/ steps I followed, i) turned off the wifi, created a wifi profile, ii) edited that file, set the variable as mode=ap, then I have connected to the network using "Connect to hidden wifi network", but my android device can't find the hotspot. :(

Comment: No worries , my other suggestion is trying an app called `ap-hotspot` it has worked for me in the past

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried ap-hotspot , I used this link:http://askubuntu.com/questions/453877/starting-wireless-hotspot-but-nothing-happens , it worked somewhat, I could find the wifi hotspot channel using my tab, but each time I tried to connect, it shows authentication error( I am sure I am typing the password correctly). :/

Comment: do you have `hostapd`, `dnsmasq`and `bridge-utils` installed?

I think `dnsmasq` and `burdge-utils`handle the authentication and address leasing stuff

Comment: my bad , its supposed to say bridge-utils . i cant change it yet

Comment: Thanks, I had dnsmasq , but I didn't have bridge-util, I will check now! :)

Comment: Sigh, I tried again using the ap-hotspot, it shows the same problem, "Authentication error". :( | Downloaded all the things you said, but do you think I need to restart and try?

Comment: It could help as dnsmasq starts at startup , other than that maybe try triple checking the password

Comment: It didn't work. I have checked password :( It's sure that I am not mistaking while entering the password.  I have verified that several times. Anyways, thanks for everything. :)

Comment: Happy to help , sorry i couldnt give you a positive solution :(