# ap-hotspot not working after update to 15.04 (64 bit)

Tags: networking, wireless, 64-bit, 15.04, ap-hotspot

I have recently updated to Ubuntu 15.04 (64 bit). My `ap-hotspot' configuration was functional in the earlier installation.

In the current scenario, the devices present around my computer are no longer able to **see**  the Wifi access point.

Could I be given instructions on what has to be done?

PS: I have also tried using the 'Create access point' using the Network icon in system settings, (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html) and it is not working

Comment: try this way : http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot

Comment: As mentioned already in the question, it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install older version of hostapd. I have on ubuntu 15.04 hostapd v1.0 and ap-hotspot v0.3-1 from webupd8 ppa. There is instruction how to do this.

https://askubuntu.com/a/453889/316028