# ap-hotspot hostapd downgraded repo not available

Tags: hostapd, ap-hotspot

I have followed the various posts regarding hotspot on 14.04 all follow the same steps as this one

["Starting Wireless Hotspot..." but nothing happens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453877/starting-wireless-hotspot-but-nothing-happens)

Which suggests that there is a bug in hostapd and it should be rolled back

however the repo of the working older version hosted here

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb

Is no longer available. Anyone know how to get fixed version of hostapd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you gave shows to use the old version, current version is 2.2, here is 2.1

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_2.1-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
```

[From this guide.](http://codewriteup.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/tested-working-set-up-wifi-hotspot-on.html)

Comment: So the latest version is the fixed version?

Comment: Fixed how ?????

Comment: Sorry post was vague I am on my phone. Updated with link to instructions that say repo version is/was buggy

Comment: Did you try it yourself ?

Comment: I have no idea which version I started with but I was having the reported issue with ap-hotspot so removed hostapd and tried to install from link above and it is not available. Reinstalled from repo and issue is same - ap-hotspot fails to start up properly

Comment: Updating a new answer